# Can you query Solr to compare a field value to the result of a Function?

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a use case where I want to search a Solr Index and find all documents where all of the terms in a field are in the query.

The query may have more terms that are not in the field. I'm only concerned with the documents where the query matches all the terms in the field.

So let's say I have the following documents:

```
[{
   field: term1 term2 term3
 },
 {
   field: term3 term4 term5
 }
 {
   field: term2 term3
 }]
```

When I query Solr with

```
field: (term2 term3 term4)
```

I'd want only the 3rd document. Also if I query with

```
field: (term2 term3 term4 term5)
```

I'd want both the second and the 3rd document.

So far I've tried adding another field to the index for each document that is just the count of the terms and then doing a filterquery that looks like:

```
fieldTermCount:{!func v="sum(termfreq(field, 'term2'), 
                             termfreq(field, 'term3'), 
                             termfreq(field, 'term4'))"
               }
```

But it doesn't seem to do anything to the result set.

When I add the `sum` function to the Field List, it properly calculates the number of matching terms as expected, but I can't seem to figure out how to compare that calculated value to the `fieldCount` on the document.

Comment: What is the cardinality of `field`? How many values can it have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out my problem.

I modified the `filterQuery` a bit to be the following:

```
{!frange u=0 l=0}
    sub(fieldCount,
        sum(termfreq(field, 'term2'), 
            termfreq(field, 'term3'),
            termfreq(field, 'term4')
           )
        )
```

What's going on here is I'm taking the `fieldCount` and subtracting the number of matching terms from it. Then doing a range query to only bring back documents that have `0` from that operation (i.e. no terms were not matched).

Also note that this only works because the terms in my documents never repeat. If the terms repeat in your documents, you'll probably have to do an `if` function call that returns only `1` or `0` if the `termfreq > 0`.